# I want to pass the value one component to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm learning reactjs, and I want to pass the data after the `onSubmit` event to another component to use the data.

For example:

in `main.js` file component

```
handleSubmit(e){    
    var value = this.state.name;    
}
```

Here I want to pass the data to `Data.js` file

```
finalData(){    
    var answer = //value data    
}
```

I have looked at many sources, but I didn't get a proper answer. Thank you

Comment: How are main.js & Data.js files are connected? Please show how have you used them.

Answer (score 0):

**Use props or context to share data between components**
In react you pass data between components using props.

Have a look at the documentation here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

If your components are not in close proximity in the component hierarchy you can consider using react context.

See the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to share state in reactjs. For example:

1. use global state tree, such as `mobx`
2. use context, just like `redux` or native `createContext`
3. use common parent to pass `props`
4. use hooks API

You can try any of these methods, `mobx` is simple, `redux` is industrialized, `props` is a easy way to share simple private state.